# How do I fix this duplicate erasor

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, duplicates, erase

This is in C++. So I have this chunk of code where I give it a vector and I want to erase the duplicates. I looked up this method, but I guess I did something wrong, because it still gives me the entire vector.

```
 void pokajiResheniq(vector<int> &answers){
   sort(answers.begin(), answers.end());
   answers.erase(unique(answers.begin(), answers.end()), answers.end());
      for(int a: answers){
          cout<<a<<" ";
      }
 }
```

Comment: What does "it still gives me the entire vector" mean? Can you [edit] the question and make the shown code meet all requirements for a [mre] by showing: 1) the code that populates a vector, 2) calls the function, 3) the resulting output. Everyone should be able to cut/paste the code ***exactly as shown*** into an empty file, then compile, run, and reproduce your results.

Comment: [not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/GMazdqx59).

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay to me

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void makeunique( vector<int> &answers ){
   sort(answers.begin(), answers.end());
   answers.erase(unique(answers.begin(), answers.end()), answers.end());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> answers{ {1,2,2,3,3,4,2,1,4 }};

    makeunique( answers );
    for(int a: answers){
          cout<<a<<" ";
    }

}
```

Result:

```sh
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
1 2 3 4
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Ej38c1rqY